# android app is not compatible on tablet (Model number : GT-P5210)

Tags: android, permissions, google-play, android-manifest

The application on the store is incompatible only on Samsung Tablet (Model number: GT-P5210 Android version: 4.4.2). These are the permissions and the  used in the android manifest:

Android permissions:

```
android.permission.INTERNET
ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION    
WAKE_LOCK
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
android.permission.BLUETOOTH
android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
```

Android uses-feature:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:required="false" android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00010001" android:required="false" />

<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: The problem is that once i'm on tablet (Model GT-P5210) i cannot download the app from the play store...But on devices i can download it.